# Notation: What is the scope of a sum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, summation

I would interpret $\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i + y$ as $x_1 + x_2 + y$, but I would interpret $\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i + y_i$ as $x_1 + y_1 + x_2 + y_2$. I realize this is a little inconsistent. Should the latter be written as $\sum_{i=1}^2 (x_i + y_i)$?

Or, in other words, does the sum operator have precedence over + and - ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be written with parentheses to avoid ambiguity, yes.  If you think about the "sum" symbol as a function, it makes sense:

$$
\sum(\cdot)
$$

This is a function which takes a list $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$ of numbers (or other mathematical objects which you might want to add), and adds them in order.  This list could be finite or infinite: the "sum" function figures out how long the list is, and adjusts its indexing accordingly (i.e. if there are 10 things in the list, your index will go from $1$ to $10$).

If you want to add a sequence which is itself the addition of two sequences, like your example of $\{x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2\}$, you'll need to drop the whole sequence into the function:

$$
\sum(\{x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2\})=\sum_{i=1}^2(x_i+y_i)
$$

For finite sums of numbers, we *always* have the property that

$$
\sum(\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}+\{y_1,y_2,\ldots\})=\sum(\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\})+\sum(\{y_1,y_2,\ldots\})
$$  however the following would have a different interpretation:

$$
\sum(\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\})+\{y_1,y_2,\ldots\}
$$

Hence the parentheses!

Interesting, yet more advanced side note: "breaking up" a sum doesn't always work if the sequences are infinite!

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that if I wrote $\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i + y_i$, you would read it as $x_1 + x_2 + y_i$? Or would you have understood that I meant $x_1 + y_1 + x_2 + y_2$? Or would you just have thought "Geez, what sloppy notation!" :)

Comment: Most people would understand what is meant, but yes we would also think it was a bit sloppy =) I see $\int f+g$ all the time as well, similar confusion.

Comment: Right. But for integrals the d tends to take the ambiguity out of it. You would write $\int f + g \, \mathrm{d}x$, and not $\int (f + g) \mathrm{d}x$, right?

Comment: Correct, but sometimes people are lazy and don't put the 'dx'.

Comment: However, $\Sigma^2_{i=1} x_i + y$ would be $x_1 + x_2 + 2y$.  If that is your intention, it would be preferable to write $\Sigma^2_{i=1} (x_i + y)$.  Otherwise, one would write $y + \Sigma^2_{i=1} x_i$, which would be unambiguously taken to mean $x_1 + x_2 + y$ .

Comment: Agreed. So $\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i + y$ would be considered somewhat ambiguous, or would most people take it to mean $y+\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i$ without hesitation?

Comment: I would read it as $\Sigma^2_{i=1} (x_{i} + y)$. I suspect many people would, since the summation sign is often understood to be applied to "everything" to the right of it.